Mac Apple Notes app main window keep coming on the top
MacBook Air
Sonoma 14.5 (23F79)
Hello guys. I have an issue with Apple Notes. When opening a note in a new window above the main window, the main window will automatically jump back above the new window if I change to another app and come back by clicking the Apple Notes icon on the dock. Sometime I need to switch to another app and back for 7 times before reproduce the issue, but it normally takes 1-5 times back and forth. Does anyone have the same problem?
Things I tried to fix it:

reboot my Mac. didn't work.
close or minimise the main window. The main window will be reopened automatically.
move the main window to another space. It will bring me to the space where the main window locates.
close the iCloud for Apple Note and open it again. didn't work.

